# Drawing Oracle spatial geometries with sharp map

Tags: c#, oracle11g, sharpmap

I need to create a simple app which can display geometries from Oracle Spatial in C#. These geometries are exported from shape file to Oracle Spatial.

I just need to pan,zoom the layers.

When i am trying to use sharp map it produces an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.112.3.60, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My code is

```
SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer vlay = new SharpMap.Layers.VectorLayer("States");
string connStr = "Server=10.2.5.55;Port=5555;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Database=myGis;";
vlay.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.Oracle(connStr, "STATES_NEW", "GEOMETRY", "OBJECTID");
MessageBox.Show(vlay.DataSource.GetFeatureCount().ToString());
mapBox1.Map.Layers.Add(vlay);
mapBox1.Map.ZoomToExtents();            
mapBox1.Refresh();
```

I am using the Oracle version of oracle11g_home2 and my operating system is windows 8. Please anyone help with me..